# How can I fix my code so I don't get a C6385 warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm having trouble with a C6385 warning in my code. I'm trying to see if two arrays will equal each other. The warning I keep getting is on the line where if(p[i] == inputGuess[j]). I have tried redoing these line but I keep getting the same warning. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong. This is also my first time programming in C++.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int* generateNumbers(int n, int m) {

    // Intialize random number
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));

    // Declare array size to generate random numbers based on what is between 1 to (m)
    int* numbers = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        numbers[i] = (rand() % m) +1;
        cout << numbers[i]<< "  " << endl;

    }

    return numbers;


}

void Game::guessingGame(int n, int m) {
    int* p;
    int sum = 0;

    // Call the generateNumber function
    generateNumbers(n, m);
    
    // Declare array based on user guesses
    inputGuess = new int[n];

    p = generateNumbers(n,m);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> inputGuess[i];
    }
    // See if the user guesses and computers answers match up
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < n; j++) {
            if (p[i] == inputGuess[j]){  //Where I keep getting the C6385 Warning
                sum++;
                break;
        }
        }
    }
    
}
```

The C6385 warning documentation states:

> The readable extent of the buffer might be smaller than the index used
> to read from it. Attempts to read data outside the valid range leads
> to buffer overrun.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6385?view=msvc-160

Comment: What is "C6385"? Most people don't actually commit Microsoft's error codes to memory.

Comment: Where is `inputGuess` defined?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should only call `srand` once. This is usually done early in `main`.

Comment: Probably not the cause of the error, but you create a memory leak when you don't store and later delete the return value of `generateNumbers`.

Comment: Also note your second `if` compares `i` instead of `j` and will go on forever or until undefined behavior makes it crash. This is probably the reason for the warning also

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of `new int[n]`.

Comment: Your inner loop does not compare j but i, so it is an endless loop.

Comment: On side note, this warning is quite impressive. Neither gcc, clang or icc detect the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `if` statement compares `i < n` instead of `j < n` and since `i` is never modified inside it will run forever. This causes the warning since you’ll access memory out of bounds. Fix the comparison.

Comment: The issue was the i<n being compared twice. I guessed I missed that typo. Thanks for your help!